# can only create 3 developer environments

Tags: power-platform

when I create power platform environments, they show as created by my username, and I'm an admin in that environment.

This causes a problem when creating developer environments, as there's a limit of 3 dev environments per user, meaning I cannot provision more than 3 environment.

I cannot remove myself as a user from other development environments however, so I am effectively limited to creating 3 developer environments.

Am I doing something incorrect here?